# how to control the logs in svnserve in windows

Tags: svn

Am using svn 1.7.4 on windows 7

How can i configure log file

For a single client log in(open repository using Tortoisesvn) process it generate lot of logs which is not understandable.

```
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.673494Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) / SVN/1.7.2 TortoiseSVN-1.7.4.22459
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.677495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) / SVN/1.7.2 TortoiseSVN-1.7.4.22459
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.679495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) / SVN/1.7.2 -
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.679495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos get-latest-rev
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.679495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos reparent /
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.680495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos check-path /@13
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.680495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos get-dir / r13 props
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.680495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) / SVN/1.7.2 TortoiseSVN-1.7.4.22459
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.682495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) / SVN/1.7.2 TortoiseSVN-1.7.4.22459
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.682495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos get-latest-rev
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.682495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos reparent /
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.682495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos stat /@13
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.682495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos get-locks /
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.683495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) / SVN/1.7.2 TortoiseSVN-1.7.4.22459
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.683495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos get-latest-rev
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.683495Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/venkateshkumarg/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos get-dir / r13 text
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.712498Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/venkateshkumarg/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) / SVN/1.7.2 TortoiseSVN-1.7.4.22459
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.714498Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) / SVN/1.7.2 TortoiseSVN-1.7.4.22459
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.717499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) / SVN/1.7.2 TortoiseSVN-1.7.4.22459
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.723499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) /tags SVN/1.7.2 TortoiseSVN-1.7.4.22459
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.723499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos get-latest-rev
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.723499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos reparent /tags
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.723499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos stat /tags@13
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.723499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos open 2 cap=(edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries depth mergeinfo log-revprops) /Test SVN/1.7.2 TortoiseSVN-1.7.4.22459
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.723499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos get-latest-rev
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.723499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos reparent /Test
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.723499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos stat /Test@13
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.724499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos get-locks /Test
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.724499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos get-dir /Test r13 text
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.724499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos get-locks /tags
7668 2012-08-13T09:21:53.725499Z 127.0.0.1 harry Users/satheesh/Desktop/SVN/svn1.7/Repos get-dir /tags r13 text
```

I need to control logs,
That is for certain events such as log in, get i need to log single entry in log file... Like

```
[Event-name] success [user-name] - time

eg: OpenRepos success harry 2.39-8/13/12
Set label Success harry 2.45-8/13/12
```

is it possible in svnserve? Please help me if it is.